# Inside a div, I have an image, then paragraph, then image at the end. I can't get the second image to be 'inside' the paragraph

Tags: image, html, division, word-wrap, paragraph

So, I have a div, and inside it I've got 3 things;
1.  An image (a big left quotation mark)
2. a live text paragraph
3. another image at the end (a big right quotation mark).

The first image, when it's put in the div, causes the text to wrap, which is great.  It appears to be part of the paragraph.

My issue:  I can't get the second image to be 'inside' the paragraph at the end.  It is pushed below the paragraph area.  I want it to 'wrap' with my paragraph text.

```
#textarea {
width: 185px;
height: 70px;
padding: 49px;
```

}

```
#textarea p {
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #4D6F79;
line-height: 230%;
text-align: center;
-webkit-margin-after: 0em;
-webkit-margin-before: 0em;
```

}

```
<div id= "textarea">
            <img src="images/leftquote.png" width="36" height="43" alt="left quotation" align="left"/>
            <p>The kids really loved it!</p>
            <img src="images/rightquote.png" width="32" height="20" alt="right quotation" align="right"/>
        </div>
```

Any help/ideas would be much appreciated!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by you want your second image in your paragraph but I know a decently easy and cheap way to use css to relocate your second image to be where you want...
First put an ID on your image:

```
<img id='image2' src="images/rightquote.png" width="32" height="20" alt="right quotation" align="right"/>
```

Then use CSS to reposition it:

```
<style>
#image2 {
position:relative;
top:-50px; // These numbers are just examples you can change them to anything to properly reposition your text.
left:20px;
z-index:-1; //depending on whether you want your image infront or behind the text you can change your z-index to either a positive number e.g.(5) or negative number e.g.(-2).
}
</style>
```

If you are worried about different formattings across different browsers they would not appar to be hugely different just off this positing but there is another way to do this if you are ok with wrapping your text around your image using overflow. Ex:

```
 <div class='floating-eg'>
<p>The kids really loved it!</p>
        <img class='left' src="images/rightquote.png" width="32" height="20" alt="right quotation" align="right"/>
</div>
<style>
.floating-eg {
    overflow: auto;
}
p {
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

You can see a related example of wrapping [here](http://jsfiddle.net/leegee/vpjjB/).

Comment: here's an image if you want to take a look at it.  http://www.flickr.com/photos/77703125@N07/8371503407/in/photostream

Comment: @Anne: I think the easiest way is to just reposition your image... but this also may be helpful using <div>paragraph<img src="yourimage.png"></div>So atleast your image is in-line and not outside the block... Either way you may have to adjust the position a little bit; but the code I posted above would do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, positioning the image independently doesn't display the same across all browsers.  It works in Chrome, but Explorer and Firefox, it is lower (not aligned with the text).

Comment: The overflow caused some strange things to happen.  It put a scrollbar in and reformatted my text a little.  Hmmm.  Well, thanks for your help anyway.  I think I might just absolute position it, and then only show in Chrome (if I get this interview).  :D